# why deployVeniaSampleData.sh runs out of memory

Tags: php, composer, script, pwa, venia

Trying to run the Venia sample data deploy script

```
bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh --yes
```

but keeps getting

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1293950976) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1293950976) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
deployVeniaSampleData.sh: line 15: 20987 Killed                  ${composer} require ${composerParams} $(printf "${moduleVendor}/%s:dev-master@dev " "${moduleList[@]}")
```

my `cli/php.ini` contains lines

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
memory_limit = -1
```

Should something be changed in the script ? Thank you

EDIT:
tried without the `--yes` argument as well